# VScode can't find python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I've set up a test in VScode, if I normally run it in the powershell it works fine, but I'm struggling in finding how to properly set it as a test in vscode.

I've already tried all of the thing I found so:

- addedd an `__init__.py` file in the test directory
- in the command palette tried the configure test -> unittest -> .root -> test_, nothing happens
- uninstalled python extension, reinstalled it and doing the process again
- this is my settings.json:

```
{
   "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
       "-v",
       "-s",
       "./Tutto",
       "-p",
       "*test*.py"
   ],
   "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
   "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
   "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
       "."
   ]
}
```

No errors, it just can't find tests.

The project is in the Tutto folder, the scripts are in a folder named src and the test file in another folder inside src named test (where there is the test_blabla.py and the **init**.py)

edit: I found a workaround by replacing  `"./Tutto"` in the `setting.json` with the entire path of the test folder, and now at least the test extension is working fine, but 2 things still remains:

- I don't have the run test and debug test functionalities in the code
- Now the entire VSCODE is pointing at the tests for the "Tutto" project, but what if I have another project with its own test folder? If I replace the path with "." it does not work

Comment: Then don't configure Python testing in global user settings, but move it info workspace-specific settings. You'll have individual configuration for your project.
Also, you can't use paths relative to a workspace in user settings, because it's not specific to any workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put the general configuration for Python testing into your [user settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), that means general configuration that's common to all workspaces (projects). You can't use any workspace-specific relative paths here obviously. These settings may be used as default values when workspace-specific settings don't override them.

The easiest way to locate the global user-specific `settings.json` file is to use the command "*Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)*". Of course you can also use the *Settings editor*, it actually manipulates with that file, but some settings can only be changed in the file.

And then configure the workspace specific settings (e.g. paths relative to a workspace) in the [workspace-specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings) file. Here you can also change (override) values configured in the user-specific settings.

The workspace-specific `settings.json` file is located in the `.vscode` subdirectory of your workspace root directory. You can also edit using the *Settings editor*, just switch to the *Workspace* tab.

Comment: Ok got it, the thing is that I think I mis created the workspace, as the workspace is PYSCRIPTS, so `C:\Users\Sparapan.F.GRUPPOFIN\Desktop\pyscripts`, while in my mind there was that pyscripts is the folder with all of the projects' folders. Hence now I have only one .vsocde folder inside PYSCRIPTS. Is there a way to change the workspace with the folders inside PYSCRIPTS?

Comment: @Federicofkt Go to `File > Open Folder...`, click the pyscripts and click **select folder** directly.